# Groovy xml request parsing

Tags: xml, groovy, namespaces

I am new to groovy.

Trying to parse some xml request, without luck for some time.

As Final result:

1. I want to check if xml request "RequestRecords" has "DetailsRequest" atrribute;
2. Get "FieldValue" number where "RequestF" has FieldName="Id".

Also, for some reason I cannot use XmlSlurper as it returns false to 'def root = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)'.

```
def env = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", 'env');
def ns0 = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://tempuri.org/", 'ns0')

def xml = '''<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<env:Body>
    <ns0:Request1>
        <ns0:Request_Sub>
            <ns0:RequestRecords TableName="Header">
                <ns0:RequestF FieldName="SNumber" FieldValue="XXX"/>
                <ns0:RequestF FieldName="TNumber" FieldValue="30"/>
            </ns0:RequestRecords>
            <ns0:RequestRecords TableName="Details">
                <ns0:RequestF FieldName="Id" FieldValue="1487836040"/>
            </ns0:RequestRecords>
        </ns0:Request_Sub>
        <ns0:isOffline>false</ns0:isOffline>
    </ns0:Request1>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>'''

def root = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)

println ("root" + root)

assert "root_node" == root.name()
println root_node
```

Even assertion of root node fails.

Answer (score 1):

Given that XML, you can use XmlSlurper to get the answers to your two questions like so:

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

// I want to check if xml request "RequestRecords" has "DetailsRequest" atrribute
List<Boolean> hasAttribute = root.Body
                                 .Request1
                                 .Request_Sub
                                 .RequestRecords
                                 .collect { it.attributes().containsKey('DetailsRequest') }
assert hasAttribute == [false, false]

// Get "FieldValue" number where "RequestF" has FieldName="Id".
String value = root.Body
                   .Request1
                   .Request_Sub
                   .RequestRecords
                   .RequestF
                   .find { it.@FieldName == 'Id' }?.@FieldValue

assert value == '1487836040'
```

Comment: If I understood correctly "hasAttribute" should return true if phrase is found, somehow  it returns false all the time, example searching for "Details", ".containsKey('Details') ."
Value search works - thanks.

Comment: Any suggestion, why ".collect { it.attributes().containsKey.." does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Either XmlSlurper or XmlParser should work fine.  From what I can see, they appear to be functionally equivalent.  They only differ in memory usage and performance.

It looks like you copied this code from the example in the javadoc, without realizing what some of the pieces mean.  Clearly, the assertion for the "root node" fails because the name of the root node from the example was "root_node", but it's "Envelope" from your code.

Not sure why you're saying that XmlSlurper doesn't work.  Your code sample using it doesn't even use it.

Comment: So what correct assertion should be in this case?
    assert root.name() == 'Envelope' 
also fails.

Comment: It's easy enough to add 'println "root[${root.name}]"' before the assertion to verify what it is.  It shows "Envelope" for me.